# How to skip a row in Python MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I have a table I want to edit in MySQL using Python, and want to edit only certain rows and skip others.

What I need this for is more complex than in this example, for example a time dependent change in an object the table took data from, but this is the simplest thing I need.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM given_table")
result = cursor.fetchall()
for row in result:
    whatto = "{Name}".format(Name=row['Action'])
    if whatto == "Skip" :
        #instruction to print row number
        #instruction to skip rest of the loop
    #other instructions
```

How do I tell Python to skip a row and give me the row number (or row number from the selection if I did it with an outset)?

If I write "print(row)", it will print me the row contents, and if I say "print(row[0])", it will print me the contents in column 1.

Comment: You can use `continue` inside your if-statement to make the loop continue with the next row instead (effectively skipping everything after the `continue` statement). You can keep the id in a list if you need to process them later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> give me the row number

[`enumerate`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0279/) can be used if you need both element and its' position in list or other iterable

> How do I tell Python to skip a row

[`continue`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#continue) placed inside loop body *continues with the next cycle of the nearest enclosing loop.*

Using mentioned in your case

```
for inx, row in enumerate(result):
    whatto = "{Name}".format(Name=row['Action'])
    if whatto == "Skip" :
        print(inx)
        continue
    #other instructions
```